# Underscore template conditional can be reduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js

I have 11 data items and would like to print them as a group. Each group will have header and at the end of the group I need to print `continue` label.

For that, I use this Underscore template and multiple conditions.  I'd like to make this more compact.

```
<script type="text/template" id="header">
<div id="recourseParameter">
    <h1> Parameter : <%= parameterCode %>  </h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=5>header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
</script>
<script id="closer" type="text/template">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
<script id="footer" type="text/template">
    </tbody>
    </table>
        <span>All are done</span>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="recourseParameterTemp">

    <% var limit = 3, dLength = recourseParameter.length %>
    <% var done = false %>
    <% _.each(recourseParameter, function (item, index) { %>

            <% if (index % limit == 0 )  { %>
                <%= _.template($('#header').html())({"parameterCode":parameterCode}) %>
            <% } %>

            <% if(item.description) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=5><%= item.description %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>

            <% if ((index+1) % limit == 0 )  { %>
                    <%= _.template($('#closer').html())() %>
                        <span>Continue ... </span> 
                    </div>
            <% }  %>

    <% }) %>

    <%= _.template($('#footer').html())() %>

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, it looks like you want to render tables with 3 records each, with the `#header` template for the top of each table and the `#closer` template for the bottom of each table, except for the last one, which should end with `#footer` instead of `#closer`.

First, the little things:

1. I think you have some unused variables in your code: It looks like `dLength` and `done` are never used.
2. `limit` is a magic number and seems out of place in your template. If I were you I would pass that number to the template function along with your other data.
3. You render `<div id="resourceParameter">` several times, but element IDs must be unique in a document. We shouldn't re-use an ID.
4. For the last table, the `</div>` is never rendered, so the above div is never closed! Fixing this is discussed below.
5. You're compiling templates inside of templates, which means that every time the outer template is rendered, you recompile the inner template, which is unnecessary and negates most of Underscore.js' rendering speed advantage. Fixing this is discussed toward the end.

### Deal with groups of items, not index math

Now, on to the meat of the question. I think the biggest code smell here is the modulo arithmetic, i.e. `<% if(index % limit == 0 ) { %>` et al. This works, but it's hard to read. Instead, we can make the code match our *intent*: We want tables with 3 records each, so let our code deal with the data in groups of 3. This saves us from having to do arithmetic on their indexes—or worring about their indexes at all. Changing only the `#recourseParameterTemp` template, we have this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="recourseParameterTemp">
    <% var group %>
    <% while(group = recourseParameter.splice(0, limit), group.length) { %>
        <%= _.template($('#header').html())({ "parameterCode": parameterCode }) %>

        <% _.each(group, function (item, index) { %>
            <% if(item.description) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=5><%= item.description %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>

            <% if(recourseParameter.length) { %>
                    <%= _.template($('#closer').html())() %>
                    <span>Continue ... </span> 
                </div>
            <% }  %>
        <% }) %>
    <% } %>
    <%= _.template($('#footer').html())() %>
</script>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu4dwty2/4/) of it in action.

I think further improvements are possible, however. For one thing, why is `<div id="recourseParameter">` inside a sub-template, but `</div>` is inside the main template? Not only is this an odd inconsistency, it actually introduced the missing `</div>` bug mentioned above. We can fix this by moving `<span>Continue...</span>` and `</div>` into the `#closer` template, and also adding `</div>` to the `#footer` template (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu4dwty2/5/)), but the bug points to a more general code smell: Templates with no closing tags, or no opening tags. If a template closes all of the tags it opens, it's much easier to notice problems like our missing `</div>`.

### The single responsibility principle

We usually talk about the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as it relates to object-oriented programming, but it's very useful here, too: Our templates are meant to isolate blocks of code that are related, and a great template has a *single responsibility*. Our `#recourseParameterTemp` template has a bunch of responsibilities—it iterates through the data, it decides whether or not to render each `<tr>`, and it decides what kind of footer render. That's too much! Using this principle, a number of possible improvements reveal themselves.

In my changes, I introduced an additional loop, i.e. I put a `while` around the `_.each`. This makes it a little harder to read, but also reminds us that it's often good to extract the inside of a loop into a sub-template that has a single responsibility. Extracting the inside of the `while` loop into a template called `#groupTmpl` (along with the `#closer`/`#footer` changes mentioned above) gives us this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="groupTmpl">
    <%= _.template($('#header').html())({ parameterCode: parameterCode }) %>

    <% _.each(group, function (item, index) { %>
        <% if(item.description) { %>
            <tr><td colspan=5><%= item.description %></td></tr>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
    <% if(recourseParameter.length) { %>
        <%= _.template($('#closer').html())() %>
    <% } else { %>
        <%= _.template($('#footer').html())() %>
    <% } %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="recourseParameterTmpl">
    <% var group %>
    <% while(group = recourseParameter.splice(0, limit), group.length) { %>
        <%= _.template( $('#groupTmpl').html() )( {
                recourseParameter: recourseParameter,
                parameterCode: parameterCode,
                group: group } ) %>
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Our intent has become clearer. We see that `#recourseParameterTmpl`'s *single responsibility* is to render a sub-template (`#groupTmpl`) once for each `group`, and that's all it does. This makes it easier to see the intent of the rest of the code, now in `#groupTmpl`. It also makes it easier to see that `#groupTmpl` still has multiple responsibilities: It renders the `#header` sub-template, it loops through each item in `group`, and it decides what kind of footer to render.

(You probably also noticed that I changed `#recourseParamaterTemp` to `#recourseParameterTmpl`; I did this just because "temporary" is frequently shortened to "temp" in programming; "tmpl" is less ambiguous.)

### One footer template

We could extract the inside of the `_.each` loop into a sub-template, but I think we can agree that that's probably overkill. The main thing we can improve here is that `#groupTmpl` is deciding what kind of footer to render, but that shouldn't be its responsibility. Instead, we should just render one template, and let that template decide what the footer should look like. Looking at our existing `#closer` and `#footer` templates, we can see that they're almost identical, except for the contents of `<span>`. It makes sense to consolidate these into one template. Removing `#closer` entirely, `#footer` and `#groupTmpl` now look like this ([here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu4dwty2/7/)):

```
<script type="text/template" id="footer">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span>
            <%= recourseParameter.length ? "Continue..." : "All are done" %>
        </span>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="groupTmpl">
    <%= _.template($('#header').html())({ parameterCode: parameterCode }) %>

    <% _.each(group, function (item, index) { %>
        <% if(item.description) { %>
            <tr><td colspan=5><%= item.description %></td></tr>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>

    <%= _.template($('#footer').html())({ recourseParameter: recourseParameter }) %>
</script>
```

Now `#groupTmpl`'s intent is very clear, and we don't have any duplicated footer code.

### Self-contained templates close their own tags

This is looking pretty good, but we still have the problem I mentioned above: `#header` opens tags that it doesn't close, and `#footer` closes tags that it doesn't open.

An alternative is to combine those templates into a single `#wrapper` template. Since Underscore.js templates don't have good support for "nested" templates, this gets a little hairy, unless we do one simple thing—which we ought to do anyway: Initialize the sub-template functions outside of the template itself. Instead of doing this:

```
<%= _.template($('#groupTmpl').html())( ... ) %>
```

We should do this, in our JavaScript:

```
var groupTmpl = _.template( $('#groupTmpl').html() );
```

...for each of our templates, and then pass the compiled template functions as locals when we use a template, which will allow us to do this in a template:

```
<%= groupTmpl( ... ) %>
```

In addition to looking cleaner, this avoids recompiling the sub-template every time the (outer) template is compiled, as mentioned above.

Along with this, instead of passing around a bunch of variables (`recourseParameter`, `parameterCode`, etc.) among our templates, it's probably a good idea to use the `variable` option to `_.template`. That is, when we call `var tmpl = _.template(html, { variable: 'locals' })`, then render it with `tmpl({ foo: "bar" })`, `foo` will be available as `locals.foo` inside the template, instead of just `foo`. While this seems less convenient, it lets us just pass `locals` to sub-templates instead of specifying the whole object. Instead of passing `{ variable: 'locals' }` every time we compile a template, though, we can set it globally using `_.templateSettings.variable = 'locals'`.

### Finally...

...we end up with templates that look like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="wrapperTmpl">
    <div id="recourseParameter">
        <h1>Parameter : <%= locals.parameterCode %></h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan=5>header</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%= locals.bodyTmpl(locals) %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span>
            <%= locals.recourseParameter.length ? "Continue..." : "All are done" %>
        </span>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="groupTmpl">
    <% _.each(locals.group, function (item, index) { %>
        <% if(item.description) { %>
            <tr><td colspan=5><%= item.description %></td></tr>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="recourseParameterTmpl">
    <% locals = _.defaults({ bodyTmpl: locals.groupTmpl }, locals) %>
    <% while(locals.group = locals.recourseParameter.splice(0, locals.limit), locals.group.length) { %>
        <%= locals.wrapperTmpl( locals ) %>
    <% } %>
</script>
```

And JavaScript that looks like this:

```
_.templateSettings.variable = "locals";

var tmpl = _.template( $('#recourseParameterTmpl').html() ),
    locals = {
        limit: 3,
        parameterCode: "foo",
        recourseParameter: [
            { description: "Foo 1" },
            // ...
        ]
    },
    renderedTmpl
;

locals.wrapperTmpl = _.template( $('#wrapperTmpl').html() );
locals.groupTmpl   = _.template( $('#groupTmpl').html() );
// You could also automate the above with jQuery, e.g.:
//
//     $("[type='text/template']").each(function() {
//       var el = $(this), id = el.attr('id');
//       locals[id] = _.template( el.html() );
//     });

renderedTmpl = tmpl(locals)

$('body').append(renderedTmpl)
```

[Here's the final fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xu4dwty2/16/) I hope that's helpful!